# Badges look way too big on iOS10 PB3

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

[image: Badge icons oversized!]

As seen in the image above, the badge icons are far larger than usual.

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 5 (Global)
- OS Version: Version 10.0 (Build 14A5322e)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.

We rely on the character `● 'BLACK CIRCLE' (U+25CF)` to render the badge icons.  It used to be really small so we increased its font size.  In iOS 10, they made it bigger so we made it way too big.  I've adjusted the size down.