# Badges missing/misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, ios-app

On every post I visit, the badges are missing from the user:

[image: Missing badges]

Sometimes, they appear somewhere else on the page:

[image: Out of place badges]
[image: Out of place badges]
[image: Out of place badges]

They are also missing from user profiles:

[image: Missing badges]

I installed iOS 10 the other day, but I *think* I had this problem before that.  I definitely didn't have this before installing 1.6.0.3.

- App Version: 1.6.0.3
- Device: iPhone 5c (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.1 (Build 14A403)

Comment: That was also reported on MSO: [Missing badges in beta app](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334820/3853934).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.4.

This is new to iOS 10.  [The badges were way too big on iOS 10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283115/235711) so I added logic to change things.  Unfortunately I failed to set the offset difference in iOS 10 so it was pulling garbage data from the stack.

See it beautifully illustrated by the static analyzer.

[image: Static analyzer showing that I forgot to assign a value.]

Comment: Best use of the static analysis tool I've seen in a while!